# Backbone.js: Can't add the same model to a set twice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have just started with backbone.js. And I'm having a problem in fetching the data from the server. Here's the response I'm getting from server.

```
[{
  "list_name":"list1",
  "list_id":"4",
  "created":"2011-07-07 21:21:16",
  "user_id":"123456"
},
{
  "list_name":"list2",
  "list_id":"3",
  "created":"2011-07-07 21:19:51",
  "user_key":"678901"
}]
```

Here's my javascript code...

```
// Router
App.Routers.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },
    initialize: function() {
    },
    index: function() {
        var listCollection = new App.Collections.ListCollection();
        listCollection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                new App.Views.ListItemView({collection: listCollection});
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("controller: error loading lists");
            }
        });
    }
});

// Models
var List = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        id: ''
    }
});

App.Collections.ListStore = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: List,
    url: '/lists'
});

// Initiate Application
var App = {
    Collections: {},
    Routers: {},
    Views: {},
    init: function() {
        var objAppRouter = new App.Routers.AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
};
```

I get the error "Can't add the same model to a set twice" on this line in Backbone.js

```
if (already) throw new Error(["Can't add the same model to a set twice", already.id]);
```

I checked out the Backbone.js annotated and found out that the first model gets added to the collection but the second one gives this error. Why is this happening? Should I change something in the server side response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `List` has `id` in its `defaults` property, which is making each instance have the same ID by default, and Backbone is using that to detect dupes.  If your data uses `list_id` as the ID, you need to tell that to Backbone by putting `idAttribute: 'list_id'` inside your `List` class definition.

As an aside, I prefer to NOT duplicate type information in object attributes (and Backbone.js agrees on this point).  Having consistent attribute names is what backbone expects and is easier to work with.  So instead of having `list_id` and `list_name`, just use `id`, and `name` on all classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this fix to add models with same id.

When adding, use: `collection.add(model,{unique: false})`

```
var __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

Backbone.Collection = (function(_super) {

    __extends(Collection, _super);

    function Collection() {
        return Collection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Collection.prototype.add = function(models, options) {
        var i, args, length, model, existing;
        var at = options && options.at;
        models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];

        // Begin by turning bare objects into model references, and preventing
        // invalid models from being added.
        for (i = 0, length = models.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (models[i] = this._prepareModel(models[i], options)) continue;
            throw new Error("Can't add an invalid model to a collection");
        }

        for (i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            model = models[i];
            existing = model.id != null && this._byId[model.id];

            // If a duplicate is found, splice it out and optionally merge it into
            // the existing model.
            if (options && options.unique) {
                if (existing || this._byCid[model.cid]) {
                    if (options && options.merge && existing) {
                        existing.set(model, options);
                    }
                    models.splice(i, 1);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // Listen to added models' events, and index models for lookup by
            // `id` and by `cid`.
            model.on('all', this._onModelEvent, this);
            this._byCid[model.cid] = model;
            if (model.id != null) this._byId[model.id] = model;
        }

        // Update `length` and splice in new models.
        this.length += models.length;
        args = [at != null ? at : this.models.length, 0];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(args, models);
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(this.models, args);

        // Sort the collection if appropriate.
        if (this.comparator && at == null) this.sort({silent: true});

        if (options && options.silent) return this;

        // Trigger `add` events.
        while (model = models.shift()) {
            model.trigger('add', model, this, options);
        }

        return this;
    };

    return Collection;

})(Backbone.Collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone prevent us to insert the same model into one collection...
You can see it in backbone.js line 676 to line 700

if you really want to insert the same models into collection,just remove the code there

```
    if(existing = this.get(model)){//here
          ...
    }
```