# Cannot add a model to backbone collection

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, equals

I have a model that has a bunch of attributes but the two of interest here are `id` and `key`. `key` is always unique, `id` not so much. When I try to add more than one model with the same `id` to a collection, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't add the same model to a collection twice
```

I am guessing this is because backbone is using the `id` to decide if two models are `===`. Is that correct? If so is there a way to override this behaviour without swapping the name of the `id` and `key` attributes? I tried messing around with the collection's `comparator` but to no avail...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724025/backbone-js-cant-add-the-same-model-to-a-set-twice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724025/backbone-js-cant-add-the-same-model-to-a-set-twice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, backbone uses and manages the `id` attribute of a model for identification. If your data uses a different property, you can set the model's [`idAttribute`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-idAttribute) to the name of your property to make backbone read the id from this property:

```
var Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "key"
});

var entry = new Entry({ key: 1, name: "an entry" });
alert("entry id: " + entry.id);
```

However, you cannot use the model's `id` property for anything else at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone prevent us to insert the same model into one collection... You can see it in backbone.js line 676 to line 700

if you really want to insert the same models into collection,just remove the code there

```
if(existing = this.get(model)){//here
      ...
}
```